# Считать выбранное значение из выпадающего списка поля модели и передать его значение в запрос?

Tags: django

Прошу Вас помочь!
Мне необходимо **в темплейте из выпадающего списка поля формы** базы данных считать значение и передать его в **запрос дочерней таблицы в представление типа CreateView , затем сразу же вывести результат запроса на экран**.
Проще говоря пользователь выбирает фамилию из списка, после того как он выбрал идет запрос в дочернюю таблицу и в темплейте отображается его фото.
Как это можно реализовать в django?

forms.py

```
class Konkurs_kForm(ModelForm): # Форма для добавления "КОНКУРС_конкурсанты"
    class Meta:
        model = Konkurs_k
        fields = '__all__'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       konkurs = kwargs.pop('konkurs') #
       super(Konkurs_kForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
       tmp_konkursk = Konkurs_k.objects.filter(konkurs=konkurs).values_list('konkursants', flat=True)
       self.fields['konkursants'].queryset = Konkursants.objects.exclude(id__in=tmp_konkursk)
```

views.py

```
class konkurs_kNew_record(CreateView):
    form_class = Konkurs_kForm
    template_name = 'main/new_konkurs_k.html'
    context_object_name = 'konks_k'

    def get_form_kwargs(self): 
        kwargs = super(konkurs_kNew_record, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['konkurs'] = self.kwargs['pk']
        return kwargs

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['info_konkurs_k'] = Konkurs.objects.filter(id=self.kwargs['pk'])
        return context
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]